# Post URL 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

Al hacer una petición con AJAX o navigator.sendbeacon obtengo este error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/notuse.html 404 (Not Found)
```

El código usado es el siguiente

```
navigator.sendBeacon('notuse.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no encuentra la página. Usa una url absoluta, algo así

```
navigator.sendBeacon('/notuse.html');
```

Asumiendo que tu dirección local es http://localhost:3000/ y que el archivo notuse.html está en la carpeta raíz de los archivos del servidor (DocumentRoot)

Comment: Ya lo he probado y obtengo el mismo error: (POST http://localhost:3000/notuse.html 404 (Not Found) ). Lo raro es que si entro en el enlace si encuentra la página